# Defining dynamically assignee when using aperte workflow inside liferay

Tags: workflow, liferay

I am using aperte workflow inside liferay 6.1. I choose aperte as it offers custom widget link with workflow tasks and so I can give to the users custome ui forms in each step.

Does it exist any way to dynamically assign the asignee of one task (the obvious way is to set the assigne to a liferay role, but it would be more efficient a java class to decide the assignee of a task).

Also is it possible to embed all activiti workflow tags inside aperte flows?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that by setting a simple attribute in process instance in vaadin widget java class.
For example,

```
ProcessInstance pi =task.getProcessInstance ();
pi.setSimpleAttribute ("selectedUser", "<liferay_screenname>");
```

Now in the AperteModeler, select the task and go to Step editor.
Go to Assignment tab, enter assignee field value as, {selectedUser}